# Translate image using PIL

Tags: python

How can I translate an image by 5 pixels in one of the four directions using PIL and python. I have seen that we can use `im.transform(size, AFFINE, data)` but I don't know how to.

Comment: What kind of output are you looking for? Do you want the the image to wrap around? Can you show an example of what the image to look like and what you have tried so far?

Comment: No, the image doesn't need to wrap around. The blank area should be black.

Answer (score 20):

`Image.transform(size, method, data)` with `method=Image.AFFINE` returns a copy of an image where an affine transformation matrix (given as 6-tuple `(a, b, c, d, e, f)`via `data`) has been applied. For each pixel `(x, y)`, the output will be calculated as `(ax+by+c, dx+ey+f)`. So if you want to apply a translation, you only have to look at the `c` and `f` values of your matrix.

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.new('RGB', (100, 100), 'red')
a = 1
b = 0
c = 0 #left/right (i.e. 5/-5)
d = 0
e = 1
f = 0 #up/down (i.e. 5/-5)
img = img.transform(img.size, Image.AFFINE, (a, b, c, d, e, f))
img.save('image.png')
```