# How to move an image (relative to another) before combining it?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I cannot figure out if it is possible to move an image's position before combining it with another one using Pillow.

I have a target image and a background. I'm not sure how to move the target image position relative to the background.

> Example, move the target 50px to the left of its original location on the new image so that when it is combined, the resulting image will maintain that position.

Can anyone guide me on how to achieve this with Pillow? Or point me towards another module?

Comment: Does it help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37584977/translate-image-using-pil

Comment: http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/reference/ImageChops.html#PIL.ImageChops.PIL.ImageChops.offset?

Answer (score 0):

You can `Image.paste` one image anywhere onto another image. For example:

```
from PIL import Image

mountain = Image.open('mountain.jpg')
tree = Image.open('tree.jpg')

mountain.paste(tree, box=(650, 350))

mountain.save('merged.jpg')
```

[image]