# how to detect image translation with only numpy and PIL

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Given two images, I need to detect if there is a translation offset between the two. I am only able to use numpy and PIL.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37584977/translate-image-using-pil) shows how to apply an (x, y) translation with PIL, but haven't found something similar for how to detect the translation.

From what I've read, cross-correlation seems to be part of the solution, and there is the [numpy.correlate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html) function. However, I don't know how to use the output of this function to detect horizontal and vertical translation coordinates.

[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lf2lc.png)

[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMSdM.png)

Comment: Please provide the two images. Thank you.

Comment: I posted an answer, then realized you specified 'NumPy and PIL only'... Sorry about that. I'll have another look tomorrow.

Comment: thanks! no worries. i know thats the more sensical approach but unfortunately for my situation i'm limited. your answer gives me some insight about how to interpret the result of correlation and the general process of finding the offset and i'll read it over!

Comment: I modified my answer with a `scipy`-free alternative.

Answer (score 5):

Since these are (almost) 2D arrays, you want the `scipy.signal.correlate2d()` function.

First, read your images and cast as arrays:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import requests
import io

image1 = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/lf2lc.png"
image2 = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMSdM.png"

img1 = np.asarray(Image.open(io.BytesIO(requests.get(image1).content)))
img2 = np.asarray(Image.open(io.BytesIO(requests.get(image2).content)))

# img2 is greyscale; make it 2D by taking mean of channel values.
img2 = np.mean(img2, axis=-1)
```

Now we have the two images, we can adapt the example in [the `scipy.signal.correlate2d()` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate2d.html):

```
from scipy import signal

corr = signal.correlate2d(img1, img2, mode='same')
```

If you want to avoid using `scipy` for some reason, then this should be equivalent:

```
pad = np.max(img1.shape) // 2
fft1 = np.fft.fft2(np.pad(img1, pad))
fft2 = np.fft.fft2(np.pad(img2, pad))
prod = fft1 * fft2.conj()
result_full = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.ifft2(prod))
corr = result_full.real[1+pad:-pad+1, 1+pad:-pad+1]
```

Now we can compute the position of the maximum correlation:

```
y, x = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(corr), corr.shape)
```

Now we can visualize the result, again adapting the documentation example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y2, x2 = np.array(img2.shape) // 2

fig, (ax_img1, ax_img2, ax_corr) = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 5))
im = ax_img1.imshow(img1, cmap='gray')
ax_img1.set_title('img1')
ax_img2.imshow(img2, cmap='gray')
ax_img2.set_title('img2')
im = ax_corr.imshow(corr, cmap='viridis')
ax_corr.set_title('Cross-correlation')
ax_img1.plot(x, y, 'ro')
ax_img2.plot(x2, y2, 'go')
ax_corr.plot(x, y, 'ro')
fig.show()
```

The green point is the centre of `img2`. The red point is the position at which placing the green point gives the maximum correlation.

[image: img1, img2 and correlation]

Comment: thanks! could you explain why we have to use 2D correlation instead  of 1D, i.e. numpy.correlate? and also, why a grayscale image would need to be converted to 'become' 2D?  does this approach require the images to be in RGB or RGBA mode?

Comment: NumPy's `correlate` is 1d, so we can't use it on 2d data. With the image, my comment was ambiguous... The image *looks* greyscale, or even binary, but it's actually RGB. So I reduced it to one channel. These images are (then) in L mode, I think you'd need to adjust the method to use `fftn` for RGB or RGBA images, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Your code has an error: notice x2, y2 = np.array(img2.shape) // 2, but in fact it should be y2, x2 = np.array(img2.shape) //2 - because the rows correspond to the y coordinate.

Comment: @yotabyte Good catch, thank you. If I had a dollar for every time I did that...