# How to find correlation between two images using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

This is inspired by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58174390/6561141).

I'm trying to find correlation between two grayscale images using Numpy. Using SciPy's [`correlate2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate2d.html) we can find this. I have found Numpy's [`corrcoef`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html) but results are different when I compared with `correlate2d`. Hence this question- Is there `correlate2d` equivalent in Numpy?

Comment: SciPy's correlate2d might just use NumPy under the hood. You could try to copy the source of correlated2d (and everything else from SciPy that it depends on). Most probably correlated2d will compute a 2d convolution with flipped and conjugated inputs exploiting the similarity between correlation and convolution.

Comment: Why not just use `scipy`? Using NumPy on its own is going to be really hard, it's going to involve a lot of Fourier transforms, and the best-case scenario is that you have re-invented `scipy.correlate2d`. `np.corrcoef` is not what you want at all — there is `np.correlate` but it's 1D.

Comment: Against my better judgment, I had a go at doing it without `scipy` :)

Comment: @kwinkunks I'm not against using SciPy, I was wondering how it was done under the hood. Thanks.

Comment: If you are interested in how things are done under the hood with open source software like SciPy don't hesitate to look in the source code directly. A good IDE like Pycharm let's you often jump directly to the sources with a single command.

Comment: @kwinkunks Thank you. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: @Trilarion Yes you are right. The correlation is found by performing convolution with one of the input array being flipped-  A call `sigtools._convolve2d(in1, in2.conj(), 0, val, bval, fillvalue)` is made. Func def: `sigtools._convolve2d(in1, in2, flip, mode, boundary, fillvalue)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this produces the same result as `scipy.correlate2d()`, where `img1` and `img2` are 2d arrays representing greyscale (i.e. single-channel) images:

```
import numpy as np

pad = np.max(img1.shape) // 2
fft1 = np.fft.fft2(np.pad(img1, pad))
fft2 = np.fft.fft2(np.pad(img2, pad))
prod = fft1 * fft2.conj()
result_full = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.ifft2(prod))
corr = result_full.real[1+pad:-pad+1, 1+pad:-pad+1]
```

The single-pixel cropping adjustment is not very elegant but that's FFTs for you: fiddly.

I just want to say that `scipy` is perfectly fine to use and I strongly recommend it. Having said that, this approach does seem to be a lot faster for the single case I tried.

Comment: Running the code with Numpy version - `1.15.4` raises `TypeError: pad() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mode'`. Specifying the parameter `mode` explicitly with default value `constant` rectifies it- `mode="constant"`. Other than that this answer is perfect. Thank you.